How to skip initial reactivity for a variable within svelte components?
I have a simple custom component in Svelte, where I use reactivity to execute some code.
<script lang="ts">
    export let liked: boolean
    $: {
         //..code that should be executed when liked is toggled ...//
    }
</script>

My problem is that when the component first mounts liked is toggled and the code is executed which is not what I want, I want to execute the code only when the user initiate the toggle.
That is why I added this initial variable here, which is making my code work as expected, but was wondering if there is a more idiomatic/clean way to do this?
<script lang="ts">
    export let liked: boolean
    let initial = true
    $: {
        if (!initial) {
            //..code that should be executed when liked is toggled ...//
        } else {
            initial = false
        }
    }
</script>


How is the liked flag set?

why not just use liked in a conditional block, given it is of boolean type?

liked is just a prop, that use bind:liked in the parent. If a user clicks on the like button then I do some transition on the component but I also trigger a popup for 2 seconds, which if I don't guard with the initial variable is triggered to all components when they mount.
